# convert dynamic web project to maven project

Tags: java, eclipse, apache, maven, plugins

I try to create a dynamic web project in eclipse and convert this project to a maven project. My project has this structure

```
src\main\java
src\main\resources
src\main\webapp
src\main\test
```

When i do Right click on the project > Configure > Convert to Maven Project, I get this error message :

```
Errors occurred during the build.
Errors running builder 'Maven Project Builder' on project 'Gestion'.
Could not calculate build plan: Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-war-plugin:2.3 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-war-plugin:jar:2.3
Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-war-plugin:2.3 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-war-plugin:jar:2.3
Could not calculate build plan: Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-war-plugin:2.3 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-war-plugin:jar:2.3
Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-war-plugin:2.3 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-war-plugin:jar:2.3
```

Answer (score 0):

I had similar issue I went to 
`http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.maven.plugins/maven-resources-plugin/2.5`
 and downloaded `maven-resources-plugin-2.5.jar and maven-resources-plugin-2.5.pom` . Copied it directly into the maven repository into the correct folder `( ~/.m2/repository/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-resources-plugin/2.5)` and then tried to do maven clean and install it woked for me.

Comment: the some problem  is still

Answer (score 0):

Working solution:

1.) close Eclipse
2.) go to c:\Users*yourUser*.m2\repository directory
3.) remove all the files called m2e-lastUpdated.properties present on all subdirectory.
restart eclipse, refresh and Update Maven Projects

My error was:

Could not calculate build plan: Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-jar-plugin:2.4 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-jar-plugin:jar:2.4

Comment: i have delete all the file names m2e-lastUpdated.properties int .m2/ directory. but there is no change it is the same probleme

Comment: do verify you have maven path configured on your system.

Comment: all yhe configuration of maven is done and when i create a mave project it's ok but the problem when i want convert the dynamic web project to the maven project

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to check the proxy settings for Maven if you're under a secure network. I experienced similar problem due to my office network security policy. Check the [Maven Install Directory] > conf > settings.xml for the correct proxy settings.

Also Check Eclipse > Window > Preferences > Maven > User settings to check if the user settings file points to the right path where your settings.xml is located.

Doing these two steps worked for me.

Comment: i dont have a proxy in network connection i have a direct network connection

Answer (score 0):

Putting the maven 2.5 plugin has not worked for you , because in your errors it's complaining about plugin version 2.3 . In your case clean up the m2e-lastUpdated.properties in *C:\Users\YourUserName.m2\repository\org\apache\maven\plugins\maven-war-plugin\2.3* folder . It worked for me.

And also if there's know settings.xml file in the .../.m2/repository/ folder , you can copy that from the M2_HOME/conf/ folder. That Settings file will have all the default settings , so nothing need to be changed.